# Change parent height based on child height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container (class of **parent**) and 3 absolute children (class of **children**). I want to change the container height based on the current child height (without scroll bar), the child is visible inside container. I tried to set height to fit-content but it's not working. Here is the code:

```js
const child1 = document.getElementById("child1"),
  child2 = document.getElementById("child2"),
  child3 = document.getElementById("child3"),
  next = document.getElementsByClassName("next"),
  back = document.getElementsByClassName("back");

for (let i = 0; i < next.length; ++i) {
  next[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    child1.style.left = "-100%";
    const temp = this.dataset.to;
    if (temp === "2") child2.style.left = 0;
    else child3.style.left = 0;
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < back.length; ++i) {
  back[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    child1.style.left = 0;
    const temp = this.dataset.from;
    if (temp === "2") child2.style.left = "100%";
    else child3.style.left = "100%";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.children {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left .5s ease;
}

#child1 {
  left: 0;
  height: 600px;
}

#child2 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#child3 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="child1">
    <h1>Child1</h1>
    <button class="next" data-to="2">Go to child2</button>
    <button class="next" data-to="3">Go to child3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child2">
    <h1>Child2</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="2">Back</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child3">
    <h1>Child3</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="3">Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use flexbox or css grid here, instead of JS?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans JS in my code just to change the current child inside the container and not related to style in html

Comment: Right, but that's something that you can _also_ do with basically pure CSS and using JS only to trigger class changes, so I was just curious why you didn't want to use CSS for the presentation side of things, with JS purely to trigger that styling cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with a very small change to your code

```js
const child1 = document.getElementById("child1"),
  child2 = document.getElementById("child2"),
  child3 = document.getElementById("child3"),
  next = document.getElementsByClassName("next"),
  back = document.getElementsByClassName("back")


const activeChild = (child) => {
  child.parentElement.style.minHeight = child.offsetHeight + "px"
  return child;

}
for (let i = 0; i < next.length; ++i) {
  next[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    child1.style.left = "-100%";
    const temp = this.dataset.to;
    if (temp === "2") {
      child2.style.left = 0;
      activeChild(child2)
    } else {
      child3.style.left = 0;
      activeChild(child3)
    }
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < back.length; ++i) {
  back[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    child1.style.left = 0;
    activeChild(child1)
    const temp = this.dataset.from;
    if (temp === "2") child2.style.left = "100%";
    else child3.style.left = "100%";
  });
}

activeChild(child1); // ini
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.children {
  min-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left .5s ease;

}

#child1 {
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

#child2 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#child3 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="child1">
    <h1>Child1</h1>
    <button class="next" data-to="2">Go to child2</button>
    <button class="next" data-to="3">Go to child3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child2">
    <h1>Child2</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="2">Back</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child3">
    <h1>Child3</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="3">Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do with javascript. First I'm getting the height of all children. Then setting the height of parent accordingly. Weirdly when the children are pushed to the right, they cause vertical scrollbar to apear although they are absolute positioned. So I set the `overflow: hidden;` on parent to hide both scrollbars. and don't worry it doesn't cause the content to be hidden vertically. To prove that I have placed `h3` tags at the bottom of all children.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent"),
  child1 = document.getElementById("child1"),
  child2 = document.getElementById("child2"),
  child3 = document.getElementById("child3"),
  next = document.getElementsByClassName("next"),
  back = document.getElementsByClassName("back")
  child1Height = child1.offsetHeight,
  child2Height = child2.offsetHeight,
  child3Height = child3.offsetHeight;
  
  parent.style.height = child1Height + 'px';

for (let i = 0; i < next.length; ++i) {
  next[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    child1.style.left = "-100%";
    const temp = this.dataset.to;
    if (temp === "2") {
      parent.style.height = child2Height + 'px';
      child2.style.left = 0;
    } 
    else {
      parent.style.height = child3Height + 'px';
      child3.style.left = 0;
    }
    // console.log(parent.offsetHeight);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < back.length; ++i) {
  back[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    parent.style.height = child1Height + 'px';
    child1.style.left = 0;
    const temp = this.dataset.from;
    if (temp === "2") {
      child2.style.left = "100%";
    } 
    else {
      child3.style.left = "100%";
    }
    // console.log(parent.offsetHeight);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.children {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: left .5s ease;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#child1 {
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

#child2 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#child3 {
  left: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="child1">
    <h1>Child1</h1>
    <button class="next" data-to="2">Go to child2</button>
    <button class="next" data-to="3">Go to child3</button>
    <h3>This is bottom</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child2">
    <h1>Child2</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="2">Back</button>
    <h3>This is bottom</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="child3">
    <h1>Child3</h1>
    <button class="back" data-from="3">Back</button>
    <h3>This is bottom</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```